# PHP regex pattern to extract string like [3,4,aAn]

Tags: php, regex

With the following peace of code I want to extract values like `[3,6,AN]` from a given string:

```
$custom='[4,100,A]@erric.com';

$regexIpAddress = '/\[\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3}\,[a|A|Aa|aA|aN|Na|AN|NA|ANa||AaN|NAa|NaA|aAN|aNA]\]/';        

preg_match($regexIpAddress, $custom, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

I want to extract with the predefined regex pattern the value like `[2,4,A], [2,4,Aa],  [20,5,AaN]`.
The regex pattern I used extracts only `[2,4,A]  or [2,4,a]`.

Is there any solution to extract all possible values?

Comment: Take a look at http://regexr.com .

Comment: This one is a little more expanded  in my opinion: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern with `i`(case-insensitive modifier):

```
$re = "/\[\d{1,3},\d{1,3},[an]{1,3}\]/i";
$matched = preg_match($re, "[20,5,AaN]");

print_r($matched);  // 1

$matched = preg_match($re, "[2,5,1]");
print_r($matched);  // 0
```

Comment: Hi @ RomanPerekhrest   you answer is the correct solution for my problem.

Comment: hello, glad to help